# Menu Items not rendering in Android Emulator

Tags: android

I am trying to create a logout menu item in the top actionbar. I performed the following steps:

1) res > right click > new > android resource directory > resource type > menu > ok

2) right click on the newly created menu folder and selected new > file > main_menu.xml

3) Based from these docs https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html, I added the following xml in the main_menu.xml text view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
</menu>
```

4) In the main_menu.xml design view, I dragged a menu item into the menu. I gave it an id, a title and showAsAction set to always. I then returned to text view and noticed the following generated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:title="Logout" android:id="@+id/@+id/logout" android:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

5) I fixed the id and noticed showAsAction it was giving the following message:

```
Should use app:showAsAction with appcompat library with xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"';
```

I ran the app and the menu item never showed up.

Didding through research, I changed the xml to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:app="schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="Logout"
          android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

I even tried add this to the xml:

```
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context=".MainActivity"
```

But the menu item is not showing up on the MainActivity screen.

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should inflate the menu in onCreateOptionMenu method of activity: getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu,menu)

Comment: These two articles were also useful to me: 1) https://developer.android.com/studio/write/add-resources.html 2) http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html

Answer (score 0):

These are also useful notes from that article:

> The toolbar has been introduced in Android 5.0 (API 21). If you want
>   to use the toolbar on devices with an earlier Android release you can
>   use the downport provided by the appcompat-v7 support library.
>
> Applications with a target SDK version less than API 11 use the
>   options menu, if such a button is present on the device. The option
>   menu is displayed if the user presses the Option button. The toolbar
>   bar is superior to the options menu, as the action bar is clearly
>   visible, while the options menu is only shown on request.
>
> Entries in the toolbar are typically called actions. While it is
>   possible to create entries in the action bar via code, it is typically
>   defined in an XML resource file.
>        Each menu definition is contained in a separate file in the res/menu folder. The Android tooling automatically creates a reference
>   to menu item entries in the R file, so that the menu resource can be
>   accessed.
>
> The MenuInflator class allows to inflate actions defined in an XML
>   file and adds them to the action bar. MenuInflator can get accessed
>   via the getMenuInflator() method from your activity.
>
> @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
>   MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
>   inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);   return true; }
>
> If an action is selected, the onOptionsItemSelected() method in the
>   corresponding activity is called. It receives the selected action as
>   parameter.
>
> @Override public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
>   switch (item.getItemId()) {    You can change the visibility of the
>   toolbar at runtime. The following code demonstrates that.
>
> ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar(); actionBar.hide();
>   actionBar.show();